# Error passing a char* to printf() call

Tags: c, printf

/***** reads user's input for an entry */

```
int input_string(char *prompt, char *s, int count) 
{
    char c;

    printf(prompt);
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF 
           && c != '\n' && count > 0) {
        *s = c;
        s++;
        count--;
    }
    *s = '\0';
    return 0;
}
```

Am new to c programming. I was going through an example of a simple database program & I met this code print(prompt); , my compiler gives this error about it,

> format string is not a string literal(potentially insecure) [-werror, -wformat-security].

Kindly help in stopping the error.

Answer (score 2):

As in yout code,

```
 printf(prompt);
```

is **bad**, as it open up provision for [string formatting attacks](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Format_string_attack). You can replace that with

```
puts(prompt);
```

in case you don't intend to use any conversion specifier (and related arguments) in  your output.

Comment: Thanks Sourav, will try that.